# image doesnt expand on entire frame wx.python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxwidgets, wxpython

hey so I followed mouseVSpython tutorial on how to set an image as my background and it worked fine except the image doesn't fully expand across the frame. Maybe im missing something here but here is the code . followed by the image

```
class F_Main(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_ERASE)
        self.frame = parent

        bSizer6 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        bSizer5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        bSizer4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.lbl_WS1 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Wafer Sort 1",
                                     wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.lbl_WS1.Wrap(-1)
        # self.lbl_WS1.SetBackgroundColour( wx.Colour( 255, 255, 0 ) )
        self.lbl_WS1.SetFont(
                wx.Font(wx.NORMAL_FONT.GetPointSize(), 70, 90, 92, False,
                        wx.EmptyString))

        bSizer4.Add(self.lbl_WS1, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        self.m_filePicker1 = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString,
                                               u"Select a file", u"*.*",
                                               wx.DefaultPosition,
                                               wx.DefaultSize,
                                               wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        bSizer4.Add(self.m_filePicker1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.dateBegin = wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                               wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                               wx.DefaultPosition,
                                               wx.DefaultSize,
                                               wx.adv.DP_DROPDOWN)
        bSizer4.Add(self.dateBegin, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.timeBegin = wx.adv.TimePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                               wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                               wx.DefaultPosition,
                                               wx.DefaultSize,
                                               wx.adv.DP_DEFAULT)
        bSizer4.Add(self.timeBegin, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.dateEnd = wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                             wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                             wx.DefaultPosition,
                                             wx.DefaultSize,
                                             wx.adv.DP_DROPDOWN)
        bSizer4.Add(self.dateEnd, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.timeEnd = wx.adv.TimePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                             wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                             wx.DefaultPosition,
                                             wx.DefaultSize, wx.adv.DP_DEFAULT)
        bSizer4.Add(self.timeEnd, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.btnGenerate = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Generate",
                                     wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer4.Add(self.btnGenerate, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.m_checkBox1 = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Report WS",
                                       wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer4.Add(self.m_checkBox1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer5.Add(bSizer4, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.lbl_WS2 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Wafer Sort 2",
                                     wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.lbl_WS2.Wrap(-1)
        self.lbl_WS2.SetFont(
                wx.Font(wx.NORMAL_FONT.GetPointSize(), 70, 90, 92, False,
                        wx.EmptyString))

        bSizer3.Add(self.lbl_WS2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        self.m_filePicker2 = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString,
                                               u"Select a file", u"*.*",
                                               wx.DefaultPosition,
                                               wx.DefaultSize,
                                               wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        bSizer3.Add(self.m_filePicker2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.dateBeginWS2 = wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                                  wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                                  wx.DefaultPosition,
                                                  wx.DefaultSize,
                                                  wx.adv.DP_DROPDOWN)
        bSizer3.Add(self.dateBeginWS2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.timeBeginWS2 = wx.adv.TimePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                                  wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                                  wx.DefaultPosition,
                                                  wx.DefaultSize,
                                                  wx.adv.DP_DEFAULT)
        bSizer3.Add(self.timeBeginWS2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.dateEndWS2 = wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                                wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                                wx.DefaultPosition,
                                                wx.DefaultSize,
                                                wx.adv.DP_DROPDOWN)
        bSizer3.Add(self.dateEndWS2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.timeEndWS2 = wx.adv.TimePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                                wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                                wx.DefaultPosition,
                                                wx.DefaultSize,
                                                wx.adv.DP_DEFAULT)
        bSizer3.Add(self.timeEndWS2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.btnGenerateWS2 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Generate",
                                        wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer3.Add(self.btnGenerateWS2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.m_checkBox2 = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Report WS2",
                                       wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer3.Add(self.m_checkBox2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer5.Add(bSizer3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.lbl_FT = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Final Testing",
                                    wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.lbl_FT.Wrap(-1)
        self.lbl_FT.SetFont(
                wx.Font(wx.NORMAL_FONT.GetPointSize(), 70, 90, 92, False,
                        wx.EmptyString))

        bSizer2.Add(self.lbl_FT, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        self.m_filePicker3 = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString,
                                               u"Select a file", u"*.*",
                                               wx.DefaultPosition,
                                               wx.DefaultSize,
                                               wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        bSizer2.Add(self.m_filePicker3, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.dateBeginFT = wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                                 wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                                 wx.DefaultPosition,
                                                 wx.DefaultSize,
                                                 wx.adv.DP_DROPDOWN)
        bSizer2.Add(self.dateBeginFT, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.timeBeginFT = wx.adv.TimePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                                 wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                                 wx.DefaultPosition,
                                                 wx.DefaultSize,
                                                 wx.adv.DP_DEFAULT)
        bSizer2.Add(self.timeBeginFT, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.dateEndFT = wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                               wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                               wx.DefaultPosition,
                                               wx.DefaultSize,
                                               wx.adv.DP_DROPDOWN)
        bSizer2.Add(self.dateEndFT, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.timeEndFT = wx.adv.TimePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                               wx.DefaultDateTime,
                                               wx.DefaultPosition,
                                               wx.DefaultSize,
                                               wx.adv.DP_DEFAULT)
        bSizer2.Add(self.timeEndFT, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.btnGenerateFT = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Generate",
                                       wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer2.Add(self.btnGenerateFT, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.m_checkBox3 = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Report FT",
                                       wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer2.Add(self.m_checkBox3, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer5.Add(bSizer2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer6.Add(bSizer5, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.btnReport = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Report",
                                   wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(1000, 25), 0)
        bSizer6.Add(self.btnReport, 0, wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer6)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

        # Connect Events
        self.dateBegin.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.date_Begin)
        self.timeBegin.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TIME_CHANGED, self.time_Begin)
        self.dateEnd.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.date_End)
        self.timeEnd.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TIME_CHANGED, self.time_End)
        self.btnGenerate.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clickBtn_Generate)
        self.btnGenerateWS2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clickBtn_GenerateWS2)
        self.btnGenerateFT.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clickBtn_GenerateFT)
        self.m_filePicker1.Bind(wx.EVT_FILEPICKER_CHANGED, self.get_Path)
        self.btnReport.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clickBtn_Report1)
        self.dateBeginWS2.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.date_BeginWS2)
        self.timeBeginWS2.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TIME_CHANGED, self.time_BeginWS2)
        self.dateEndWS2.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.date_EndWS2)
        self.timeEndWS2.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TIME_CHANGED, self.time_EndWS2)
        self.dateBeginFT.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.date_BeginFT)
        self.timeBeginFT.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TIME_CHANGED, self.time_BeginFT)
        self.dateEndFT.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.date_EndFT)
        self.timeEndFT.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TIME_CHANGED, self.time_EndFT)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    def __del__(self):
        pass

    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
        """
        Add a picture to the background
        """
        # yanked from ColourDB.py
        dc = evt.GetDC()

        if not dc:
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
            dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
        dc.Clear()
        bmp = wx.Bitmap("AMD.png")
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class

    def clickBtn_Report1(self, event):
        a = self.m_checkBox1.IsChecked()
        b = self.m_checkBox2.IsChecked()
        c = self.m_checkBox3.IsChecked()

        # d = reportGrid(None)

        if (a == True and b == True):
            fileName = self.get_Path(None)
            fileName2 = self.get_PathWS2(None)
            dataWS = F_WaferSort1.report(self, fileName)
            dataWS2 = F_WaferSort2.report(self, fileName2)
            grid = reportFrame(None, list=dataWS, list2=dataWS2)
        elif (a == True and b == False):
            fileName = self.get_Path(None)
            fileName2 = self.get_PathWS2(None)
            dataWS = F_WaferSort1.report(self, fileName)
            grid = reportFrame(None, list=dataWS)

        # print(self.m_checkBox1.IsChecked())
        # print(self.m_checkBox2.IsChecked())

    def get_Path(self, event):
        a = self.m_filePicker1.GetPath()
        a = a.split("\\")
        a = "\\\\".join(a)
        return a

    def get_PathWS2(self, event):
        a = self.m_filePicker2.GetPath()
        a = a.split("\\")
        a = "\\\\".join(a)
        return a

    def get_PathFT(self, event):
        a = self.m_filePicker3.GetPath()
        a = a.split("\\")
        a = "\\\\".join(a)
        return a

    def date_Begin(self, event):
        aStringDate = self.dateBegin.GetValue().Format("%m-%d-%y")
        return aStringDate

    def time_Begin(self):
        aStringTime = self.timeBegin.GetTime()
        timeNotation = "  {0}:{1}:{2}".format(str(aStringTime[0]),
                                              str(aStringTime[1]),
                                              str(aStringTime[2]))
        return timeNotation

    def date_End(self, event):
        aStringDate = self.dateEnd.GetValue().Format("%m-%d-%y")
        return aStringDate

    def time_End(self):
        aStringTime = self.timeEnd.GetTime()
        timeNotation = "  {0}:{1}:{2}".format(str(aStringTime[0]),
                                              str(aStringTime[1]),
                                              str(aStringTime[2]))
        return timeNotation
        return aStringTime

    def date_BeginWS2(self, event):
        aStringDate = self.dateBeginWS2.GetValue().Format("%m-%d-%y")
        return aStringDate

    def time_BeginWS2(self):
        aStringTime = self.timeBeginWS2.GetTime()
        timeNotation = "  {0}:{1}:{2}".format(str(aStringTime[0]),
                                              str(aStringTime[1]),
                                              str(aStringTime[2]))
        return timeNotation

    def date_EndWS2(self, event):
        aStringDate = self.dateEndWS2.GetValue().Format("%m-%d-%y")
        return aStringDate

    def time_EndWS2(self):
        aStringTime = self.timeEndWS2.GetTime()
        timeNotation = "  {0}:{1}:{2}".format(str(aStringTime[0]),
                                              str(aStringTime[1]),
                                              str(aStringTime[2]))
        return timeNotation
        return aStringTime

    def date_BeginFT(self, event):
        aStringDate = self.dateBeginFT.GetValue().Format("%m-%d-%y")
        return aStringDate

    def time_BeginFT(self):
        aStringTime = self.timeBeginFT.GetTime()
        timeNotation = "  {0}:{1}:{2}".format(str(aStringTime[0]),
                                              str(aStringTime[1]),
                                              str(aStringTime[2]))
        return timeNotation

    def date_EndFT(self, event):
        aStringDate = self.dateEndFT.GetValue().Format("%m-%d-%y")
        return aStringDate

    def time_EndFT(self):
        aStringTime = self.timeEndFT.GetTime()
        timeNotation = "  {0}:{1}:{2}".format(str(aStringTime[0]),
                                              str(aStringTime[1]),
                                              str(aStringTime[2]))
        return timeNotation
        return aStringTime

    def clickBtn_Generate(self, event):
        fileName = self.get_Path(None)
        a = self.date_Begin(None)
        b = self.time_Begin()
        c = self.date_End(wx.adv.DateEvent())
        d = self.time_End()
        list = []
        list.append(a)
        list.append(b)
        list.append(c)
        list.append(d)
        startDate = list[0] + list[1]
        endDate = list[2] + list[3]
        startDateDateTime = datetime.strptime(startDate, "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")
        endDateDateTime = datetime.strptime(endDate, "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")
        print(startDateDateTime)
        print(endDateDateTime)
        if (endDateDateTime < startDateDateTime):
            frame = badDates(None)
            frame.Show()
        else:

            frame = F_WaferSort1(None, startDate, endDate, fileName)
            frame.getXYD()
            frame.creatFirstFrame()
            event.Skip()

    def clickBtn_GenerateWS2(self, event):
        fileName = self.get_PathWS2(None)
        a = self.date_BeginWS2(None)
        b = self.time_BeginWS2()
        c = self.date_EndWS2(wx.adv.DateEvent())
        d = self.time_EndWS2()
        list = []
        list.append(a)
        list.append(b)
        list.append(c)
        list.append(d)
        startDate = list[0] + list[1]
        endDate = list[2] + list[3]
        startDateDateTime = datetime.strptime(startDate, "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")
        endDateDateTime = datetime.strptime(endDate, "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")
        if (endDateDateTime < startDateDateTime):
            frame = badDates(None)
            frame.Show()
        else:

            frame = F_WaferSort2(None, startDate, endDate, fileName)
            frame.getXYD()
            frame.creatFirstFrame()
            event.Skip()

    def clickBtn_GenerateFT(self, event):
        fileName = self.get_PathFT(None)
        a = self.date_BeginFT(None)
        b = self.time_BeginFT()
        c = self.date_EndFT(wx.adv.DateEvent())
        d = self.time_EndFT()
        list = []
        list.append(a)
        list.append(b)
        list.append(c)
        list.append(d)
        startDate = list[0] + list[1]
        endDate = list[2] + list[3]
        startDateDateTime = datetime.strptime(startDate, "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")
        endDateDateTime = datetime.strptime(endDate, "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")
        print(startDateDateTime)
        print(endDateDateTime)
        if (endDateDateTime < startDateDateTime):
            frame = badDates(None)
            frame.Show()
        else:

            frame = F_WaferSortFT(None, startDate, endDate, fileName)
            frame.getXYD()
            frame.creatFirstFrame()
            event.Skip()


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(740, 410))
        panel = F_Main(self)
        self.Center()
```

below is the image of how it looks. Im prettu sure I can resize the image to be bigger but im sure i'll have the same problem once you maximize the window

[image]

the link to the turorial I followed is https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/

Comment: as it is currently written your question is too broad, can you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: in `F_Main.time_EndWS2` method you have 2 consecutive `return` statements (hint: only first gets executed, second won't be ever reached), what are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: sorry the return thing is my fault didn't see that but basically all im trying to do is make the background image (the dog) expand to cover the whole frame. it has a nice chunk of white that's not covered

Comment: When the window and the image don't have the same width/heigth proportion, what would you do? Lose some part of the image? Distort it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Scale` function of `wx.Image` to set the image to the size of the window.

```
def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
    """
    Add a picture to the background
    """
    # yanked from ColourDB.py
    dc = evt.GetDC()
    if not dc:
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
        dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
    dc.Clear()
    w,h = self.GetSize()
    bmp = wx.Bitmap("AMD.png")
    image = bmp.ConvertToImage()
    bmp = wx.Bitmap(image.Scale(w,h))

    dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Man this is literally what I needed !